# How to get SocketIO to work with SSL whilst listening on a port?

Tags: node.js, ssl, socket.io

I've been trying to setup SocketIO to work with SSL on my website. The SocketIO server is instantiated like this:

```
const https = require('https');
const server = https.createServer({
    path: '/ws',
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate
});
server.listen(4002);
io = SocketIO.listen(server, {secure: true});
```

My server has a SSL certificate from certbot and is running on https just fine.
The client connection looks like this:

```
socket = io.connect("https://MY_SERVERS_IP_ADDRESS:4002", {path: '/ws', secure: true, transports: ['websocket']});
```

The console gives me these errors on my website:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
MY_SERVERS_IP:4002/ws/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MMMpZ1m:1 Failed to load
```

And

```
polling-xhr.js:267 GET https://MY_SERVERS_IP:4002/ws/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MMMptP8 0 ()
```

I'm not well versed with SSL, so I hope anyone can help me with this.

Comment: This is probably not your main problem (which appears to be an SSL configuration issue), but you will need to remove `path: '/ws'` from the `io.connect()`.  Unless you configure your socket.io server to listen for that specific path, this will not work.  By default, you don't need to specifiy anything for the `path`.  The socket.io client and server are configured with their own default path.  If you change the client, you would then have to change the server to match.  Also, there is no `path` option for `https.createServer()` so that is likely being ignored.

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right track! I removed the path and made socketio listen on the same server as my API and frontend. This way the SSL certificates are accepted and everything works now.